# Rails: passing objects between model and controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

Is there a best practice for managing objects between model and controller in Rails? I've got code that clumsily hands files from controller to model and back like so:

In `document_controller.rb`:

```
tmp_file = Tempfile.new(Digest::MD5.hexdigest(rand(12).to_s))
pdf = Prawn::Document.generate(tmp_file.path(), :page_size => "A4", :skip_page_creation => true) do |posting|
  @document.process(posting)
  send_data posting.render, :filename => "#{@document.id}", :type => "application/pdf"
end
```

And in `document.rb`:

```
def process(pdf)
  pdf.start_new_page
  pdf.image self.user.logo.path, :width => pdf.bounds.width
  pdf.fill_color '#444444'
  pdf.image self.component.image_snapshot.path, :width => pdf.bounds.width
  pdf.move_down 20
  pdf.indent 20 do
    pdf.text self.component.name, :size => 24
  end
  box_start = pdf.cursor
  pdf.reflow_column_box([20, box_start-15], :width => pdf.bounds.width-20) do
    format_for_prawn(pdf, self.component.body, self.user.colour1)
  end
end
```

How can I rewrite this code so I don't have to clumsily pass the `pdf`/`posting` object around? It feels very un-Rails-like.

Thanks for your input.

**EDIT**: worse example.

Again in the controller:

```
tempfile = Magick::Image.read(@document.component.image_newsletter.path).first
overlay = Magick::Image.read(@document.user.logo.path).first.resize_to_fit(tempfile.columns)
rec = Magick::Draw.new
rec.stroke = "##{@document.user.colour1}"
rec.fill = "##{@document.user.colour1}"
rec.rectangle 0, 0, tempfile.columns, 5
lank = tempfile.extent(tempfile.columns, tempfile.rows+overlay.rows, 0 ,0)
final = lank.composite(overlay, Magick::SouthGravity, 0, 0, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
rec.draw(final)
send_data final.to_blob, :filename => "#{@document.user.name}-#{@document.id}.jpg", :type => "image/jpg"
```

This is in the controller because otherwise `send_data` can't access `final`. Any help?

Thanks again.

Comment: just my opinion but I think it's fine. Should send_data be outside the block though?

Comment: I need access to `posting` to render it and send it. No good?

Comment: Re your code, I think its fine; if you want to adjust your render function to have the `process` I guess you could do that but, to be honest, I think it makes the process more opaque. The only thing I would do differently is use a name different than `process` like `generate_report` or something more descriptive (and less likely to be duplicated in another class).

Comment: Re the block, having come to ruby from another language, things like this just seem clunky: File.open('my-file.txt', 'w') {|f| f.write("here is a string) } but they are, in fact, fine. It seems to add unncessary complexity.

Comment: That's fair enough. I'll update my question with a worse example though to see what you think. And process is just a proxy/ghost method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get that messy controller code into the model I've done this:

```
def process_media
  temp = "#{::Rails.root}/public/temporary/#{temp_file_name}"
  tempfile = Magick::Image.read(self.component.image_newsletter.path).first
  overlay = Magick::Image.read(self.user.logo.path).first.resize_to_fit(tempfile.columns)
  rec = Magick::Draw.new
  rec.stroke = "##{self.user.colour1}"
  rec.fill = "##{self.user.colour1}"
  rec.rectangle 0, 0, tempfile.columns, 5
  lank = tempfile.extent(tempfile.columns, tempfile.rows+overlay.rows, 0 ,0)
  final = lank.composite(overlay, Magick::SouthGravity, 0, 0, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
  rec.draw(final)
  final.to_blob
  final.write("#{temp}.jpg")
end
```

And I'm sending the actual file with `send_file` from the controller. Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

You can create extension methods for inbuilt Class by

```
#lib/ext/prawn/document.rb

class Prawn::Document
def process(pdf)
  pdf = self if pdf.blank?
  pdf.start_new_page
  pdf.image self.user.logo.path, :width => pdf.bounds.width
  pdf.fill_color '#444444'
  pdf.image self.component.image_snapshot.path, :width => pdf.bounds.width
  pdf.move_down 20
  pdf.indent 20 do
    pdf.text self.component.name, :size => 24
  end
  box_start = pdf.cursor
  pdf.reflow_column_box([20, box_start-15], :width => pdf.bounds.width-20) do
    format_for_prawn(pdf, self.component.body, self.user.colour1)
  end
end
end
```

And in your controller

```
tmp_file = Tempfile.new(Digest::MD5.hexdigest(rand(12).to_s))
pdf = Prawn::Document.generate(tmp_file.path(), :page_size => "A4", :skip_page_creation => true) do |posting|
  posting.process
  send_data posting.render, :filename => "#{@document.id}", :type => "application/pdf"
end
```

To load this class, you will need to require it in your `config/application.rb` file or in an initializer.

`require 'ext/prawn/document'`

Comment: That's really not all that different to putting that method in the model.